# How can I add a new row to an existing Excel spreadsheet using Perl?

Tags: excel, perl

I have created my Excel sheet *a.xls* using Perl where I have field as:

```
date         name    eid     
13/jan/2010   asa    3175
```

When I will compile next time and if date will be more than previous date then it has to update like wise:

```
date         name   eid
13/jan/2010  asa    3175
14/jan/2010  stone  3180
```

If the date will be of previous row date as last row date is `14/jan/2010` and current date is also `14/jan/2010` then it should not insert any row it should update the previous record only.

Answer (score 5):

See example in [Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Spreadsheet-ParseExcel-0.56/lib/Spreadsheet/ParseExcel/SaveParser.pm#SYNOPSIS). As I understand, AddCell method can replace existing cell or add new.

Answer (score 0):

With Excel 2007 files, using [Excel::Writer::XSLX](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Excel-Writer-XLSX-0.47/lib/Excel/Writer/XLSX.pm), you can't do this. As of release 0.47 from June 2012:

> This module cannot, as yet, be used to write to an existing Excel
>   XLSX file.

You can only create new files.

Answer (score 0):

```
    use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Excel';

    $Excel = Win32::OLE->new('Excel.Application', 'Quit');
    $Excel->{DisplayAlerts}=0;

    my $workbookpath = "D:\\temp.xlsx";
    my $workbook = $Excel->Workbooks->Open($workbookpath);
    # lets think if you created multiple sheets in an workbook, you can refer each workbook by name(Ex: sheet1 here)
    my $sheet = $workbook->WorkSheets("sheet1");
    #Insert row in a particular row value
    $sheet->Cells(8,1)->EntireRow->Insert;
    #save and close workbook, its a best practise when you are doing any excel operation
    $workbook->Save;
    $workbook->Close();
```

Comment: Instead of just blurting out a block of code, an explanation of how and why your solution solves the problem provides more value. This answer is not useful to future visitors otherwise.

Comment: Thanks @ResetACK for your suggestion.